# Create instance of a class not known at compile time

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, reflection

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Room {

}
```

and inherited classes that are not known at compile time like:

```
public class MagicRoom extends Room {

    public MagicRoom(){
        System.out.println("Creating a MagicRoom.");
    }

    public String magic = "";
}
```

or:

```
public class Dungeon extends Room {

    public Dungeon(){
        System.out.println("Creating a Dungeon");
    }

    public String keeper = "";
}
```

I have a class that I will be creating instances of these classes from:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class MazeGame {

    public static Room makeRoom(Class roomClass) 
        throws IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, 
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, 
            SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException{

        Constructor c = roomClass.getConstructor();
        return c.newInstance();

    }

}
```

makeRoom is my attempt to create a class inherited from Room which type I don't know at compile time, but I'm not sure what to put as its return type instead of Room. Because makeRoom returns a Room I get an exception if I try to use a field that belongs to an inherited class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class FactoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, 
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, 
            InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException{

        MazeGame game = new MazeGame();

        Room magicRoom = MazeGame.makeRoom(MagicRoom.class);

        /*
         * Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
         * magic cannot be resolved or is not a field
         */

        magicRoom.magic = "a"; 

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, the class is known it's `MagicRoom`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make that method generic:

```
public static <T extends Room> T makeRoom(Class<T> roomClass) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, 
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, 
        SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException{

    // This is enough, if you have 0-arg constructor in all your subclasses
    return roomClass.newInstance();
}
```

and then invoke it like:

```
MagicRoom magicRoom = MazeGame.makeRoom(MagicRoom.class);
```

Comment: Tested and accepted, I don't have enough reputation points to upvote the answer unfortunately.

Comment: Click the tick below the answer rating to accept the answer. I thought anyone could upvote?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to cast the Room object to MagicRoom.

```
MagicRoom magicRoom = (MagicRoom) MazeGame.makeRoom(MagicRoom.class);
```

Also, I know it's only an example but you should make those attributes private and use accessor/mutator methods.

e.g.

```
public class MagicRoom extends Room {

  public MagicRoom(){
    System.out.println("Creating a MagicRoom.");
  }

  private String magic = "";

  public String getMagic() {
    return this.magic;
  }

  public void setMagic(String magic) {
    this.magic = magic;
  }

}
```

Comment: Rohit's answer is actually a better alternative to mine but you should still avoid the public attributes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you're right about making the attributes public.